# CodeIgniter - return values after DB's insert

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have an form which works with my model:

```
public function addGame($data, $parent_id = '0') {

    // passing variables from POST
    ...

    // insert array
    $ins = array(
        ...
    );

    $q = $this->db->insert('games',$ins);
    $last = $this->db->insert_id();
    return site_url().'/'.$last.'/'.$slug;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function addGame() {

    $this->load->model('contrib_model');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->contrib_model->addGame($this->input->post()); //submits data
    } else {
        $this->layout->view('contribute/addGame', $data); //loads view
    }
}
```

My point is - to want this last `return` value... returned. I use compression, so I can't `echo` it (it wouldn't be apropriate anyway).

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are not using the return value in any way

Comment: Yes, because I don't know how. When I use `echo $this->contrib_model->addGame($this->input->post()); //submits data` in controller, it also throws errors.

Comment: Don't echo it but pass it to some view you are using. see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html the section `Adding Dynamic Data to the View`

Comment: Stupid me ;) Obviosly I should have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Esailija suggested, I solved this problem with creating views. First of all, I am using simple layout engine, so I had to get rid of it. Now my controller looks like this (the important part):

> ```
>   if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
>         $data['submit'] = $this->contrib_model->addGame($this->input->post()); //submits data
>         $this->load->view('contribute/emptyPage', $data); //loads view
>     } else {
>         $this->layout->view('contribute/addGame', $data); //loads view
>     }
> ```

As you can see, first loading view is different - that's pure CodeIgniter view. In contribute/emptyPage.php I have only this:

```
<?php echo $submit; ?>
```

And it works like it should - returns only new address, which I can use to redirect (with `header('Location...` for example).